# System hardware information

Tags: ros, diagnostics, cpu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any package that provides information of the computer hardware?

I need to create some modules to check the available memory, cpu usage, disk health, etc.. from a C++ application.

I was wondering if this is something that has already been done.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10053/system-hardware-information/) by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2011-05-24

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-05-25**:
Additionally, I intend to work on this, but have not had time as of yet.  Best case scenario would be something working by the end of June, or early July (2011) when I get time to work on it.  I intend to use lm_sensors and the nvidia tools for temperature and voltage monitoring.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-05-25**:
This is a duplicate of: http://answers.ros.org/question/37/pr2_computer_monitor-with-lm_sensors  As far as I know, no one has done it yet.

**Comment by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on 2011-05-25**:
Yes, but it sounds like something that every robot should check and that could be gathered an sent using the diagnostics package. Maybe someone has already done it.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-05-25**:
Sounds like something you'd get from the underlying OS, not ROS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try looking at the pr2_computer_monitor package, it might be a good starting point

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on 2011-05-27**:
Thanks, this might just be what I was looking for, I guess I didn't search the right keywords.